# using $resource in angularjs in proper way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I want to consume restful webservice where I should query service with two parameters how would I do that using **angularjs 1x $resource**

If my backend expects following query

> http://myserver:8080/?country=usa&city=newyork

```
function productResource($resource){
  return $resource("http://myserver:8080/?????????")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add methods to the resource like:

```
$resource('your_location_rest_url', {
  'find': {method: 'GET', url: 'your_location_rest_url/find', params: {country: @country, city: @city}
});
```

That adds a method location to your resource so you could do:

```
var location = new Location();
location.city="baltimore";
location.country = "USA";

location.find().$promise().then(....);
```

The key though is creating a method in your resource and configuring it with 'params'.

Comment: ok, why inside function there is two your_location_rest_url params?

Comment: the first one would be your base rest url so like /location.  The one for find would be the url for your specific url, like: /location/find